# Deserializing a jagged array via JSON.NET with types

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

So I'm trying to deserialize jagged arrays using JSON.NET.  I can deserialize them with a basic object[][] just fine, but I'd like to be able to access the properties without indexers.  Something like expression-bodied properties would be great.

The big problem here is that these arrays are key-less.

Sample of what I'm trying to deserialize: 
 [Page array for each chapter](https://www.mangaeden.com/api/chapter/4e711cb0c09225616d037cc2/) 
[Manga Information with array of chapter info arrays](https://www.mangaeden.com/api/manga/4e70e91ec092255ef700174c/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a so called anti-corruption layer. I mean, a method that converts the resulting jagged array to the desired class so the calling code will be easier to write and to read. I don't see any other solution as your json hasn't got any property name.